# Issue while reading Input from a file and passing it to a file in Batch Processing

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have an issue while reading from a input file the below shown values(FILE.txt) .
The < > symbols cause an improper read . I tired using ^(escape character but its of no use ,I also tried Double quotes("") and the result is same messed up output.

Is there anyway I can read the contents of the file in iteration with the < > = characters .
Please help

```
FILE.txt contains

A;Select * from TablenameA where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;XXX;YYY
B;Select * from TablenameB where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;AAA;YYY
C;Select * from TablenameC where time=>yesterdaytime and time<endtime;BBB;YYY


--------------SCRIPT----------------------------------
SET vFILENAME=FILE.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in (%vFILENAME%) do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l"
goto END

:process
    set VAR1=%~1
    set VAR2=%~2
    set VAR3=%~3
    set VAR4=%~4



some processing on VAR1,2,3,4 and then 

        echo PrmOne=%VAR1%>Output_%VAR1%.txt
        echo PrmTWO=%VAR2%>>Output_%VAR1%.txt
        echo PrmTHREE=%VAR3%>>Output_%VAR1%.txt
        echo PrmFOUR=%VAR4%>>Output_%VAR1%.txt
```

-----OutPut(new for each iteration) File will contain values like this for each iteration----------------

```
PrmOne=A
PrmTWO=Select * from TablenameA where time=>yesterdaytime_UPDATED and time<endtime_UPDATED
PrmTHREE=XXX
PrmFOUR=YYY
```

**Solution was provided for this But need the output in the above mentioned manner** please help
Thanks to @Aacini

```
@echo off

SET vFILENAME=FILE.txt
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in (%vFILENAME%) do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k" "%%l" < NUL
goto :EOF

:process
    set "VAR1=%~1"
    set "VAR2=%~2"
    set "VAR3=%~3"
    set "VAR4=%~4"


    set /P "=%VAR1%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR2%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR3%" & echo/
    set /P "=%VAR4%" & echo/
```

Comment: Is this another one of your **examples**.  I sure would like to know what you are doing with this: **some processing on VAR1,2,3,4 and then**.  Are we gonna see a third question today that could totally change the batch file?  You never answered my question in your previous thread.  Why are you calling out to a function.  Why don't you keep all the processing inside the FOR /F command.  Using CALL is a real time performance hit with batch files.

Comment: @Squashman Adding everything here is not a viable option .due to sheer length of code wriiten . Explaining everything would take up a lot of time and effort . Lets hope you wont see a third post with some other question . :)    and Thank you for taking time to answer my query .

Answer (score 2):

You can use delayed expansion to avoid problems with variable content output

```dos
>"Output_%VAR1%.txt" (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo PrmOne=!VAR1!
    echo PrmTWO=!VAR2!
    echo PrmTHREE=!VAR3!
    echo PrmFOUR=!VAR4!
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation from Aacini's original code.  Not necessary to call a function.  If you need to call the function then adjust accordingly.

```
@echo off

SET vFILENAME=FILE.txt
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=;" %%i in ("%vFILENAME%") do (
    >>%%~i.txt (
            set /P "=PrmOne=%%~i" & echo/
            set /P "=PrmTwo=%%~j" & echo/
            set /P "=PrmThree=%%~k" & echo/
            set /P "=PrmFour=%%~l" & echo/
            )<nul
)
```